# Trying to ping IP and save result to a text but receiving syntax error in cmd prompt when trying to run .bat file

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, command-prompt, ip-address, ping

So I made a batch file that is suppose to ping an IP address and if "TTL=" is present when pinging the address the next command is suppose to write "x.x.x.x - Online" to a text file, and if the "TTL=" is not present then write "x.x.x.x - Offline".

See code:

```
ping 192.168.1.130|find "TTL=">nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0(
    echo 192.168.1.130 - Offline > ping.txt
)else(echo 192.168.1.130 - Online > ping.txt)
ping 192.168.1.200|find "TTL=">nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0(
    echo 192.168.1.200 - Offline > ping.txt
)else(echo 192.168.1.200 - Online > ping.txt)
```

However when I run the .bat file in the cmd prompt I am receiving this result:

> ping 192.168.1.130  | find "TTL=" 1>nul
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Other than that line nothing else in the file seems to run and I see no txt in the folder location, so from that I think that it fails or exits the .bat file right after. From the information I have found from this site and Google, the syntax does not seem different so I am not sure what is causing the error or what I can do to make it functioning. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Put a space before the `>` as a number before it is considered a file number.

Comment: Also, put a space before the `(` in your `if` statements

Comment: The `IF...ELSE...` syntax is clearly defined in the help file for the `IF` command and clearly shows spaces before and after the parantheses.

Comment: Squashman is right. You are comparing `%errorlevel%` with a literal `0(`, but then there is no command to execute -> syntax error.

Comment: Yeah that works now thanks for your help every one.

Comment: @EmmisTheRed If you want to test something else with colors, just give a try for this batch script : [Scanner_IP_MAC_Colors.bat](https://pastebin.com/9jLJxyx7)